# Azure Application Gateway Missing Rule 910 and 912

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I'm trying to setup an Azure Application Gateway, in the documents I've read there are details of rules 910 (IP Reputation) and 912 (DOS attack) being available, however when I check through the list of rules in my instance of the application gateway, neither of these rules are listed.

Can someone tell me where they are, or how to enable them?

Answer (score 0):

They should be located within the OWASP 3.0 rule set .
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-customize-waf-rules-portal

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/media/application-gateway-customize-waf-rules-portal/figure1.png

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't in the list I see, my list is General, 911, 913, 920 etc..., no 910 or 912